# Large Pandas dataframe finding overlapping regions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a Pandas DataFrame in pandas with genomic regions represented by their chromosome, start position, and stop position. I'm trying to identify overlapping regions within the same chromosome and compile them along with their corresponding labels. I'm not sure if the way that I'm doing is correct-- also I want an efficient approach since my df is very large (3 million rows), so a for loop is not ideal.

Here's a sample df and expected output df:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'chromosome': ['chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1'],
    'start': [10, 15, 35, 45, 55],
    'stop': [20, 25, 55, 56, 60],
    'hg_38_locs': ['chr1:10-20', 'chr1:15-25', 'chr1:35-55', 'chr1:45-56', 'chr1:55-60'],
    'main_category': ['label1', 'label2', 'label2', 'label3', 'label1']
}

Output:

     overlapping_regions              overlapping_labels
0    (chr1:10-20, chr1:15-25)        (label1, label2)
1    (chr1:10-20, chr1:35-55)        (label1, label2)
2    (chr1:15-25, chr1:35-55)        (label2, label2)
3    (chr1:35-55, chr1:45-56)        (label2, label3)
4    (chr1:45-56, chr1:55-60)        (label3, label1)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the **pyranges** module?

Comment: How would I use it? Can you post an answer please?

Comment: Are you shure of the output you expect? I do not get the same result.

Comment: Why does `(chr1:10-20)` overlap with `(chr1:35-55)`? Are they not disjoint?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the ouput you posted in your question is wrong. Simply look are the intervall tree and the `start`, `stop` values. If you do the exercise, you'll see that he ouput you posted doesn't match. I suggest you do the following.

```
import pandas as pd
from intervaltree import Interval, IntervalTree

data = {
    'chromosome': ['chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1'],
    'start': [10, 15, 35, 45, 55],
    'stop': [20, 25, 55, 56, 60],
    'hg_38_locs': ['chr1:10-20', 'chr1:15-25', 'chr1:35-55', 'chr1:45-56', 'chr1:55-60'],
    'main_category': ['label1', 'label2', 'label2', 'label3', 'label1']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def find_overlaps(df):
    results = []
    for chromosome, group in df.groupby('chromosome'):
        tree = IntervalTree()
        for _, row in group.iterrows():
            tree[row['start']:row['stop']] = (row['hg_38_locs'], row['main_category'])

        for interval in tree:
            overlaps = tree.overlap(interval.begin, interval.end)
            if len(overlaps) > 1:
                overlapping_regions = tuple(ov.data[0] for ov in overlaps)
                overlapping_labels = tuple(ov.data[1] for ov in overlaps)
                if (overlapping_regions, overlapping_labels) not in results:
                    results.append((overlapping_regions, overlapping_labels))

    return pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['overlapping_regions', 'overlapping_labels'])

output_df = find_overlaps(df)
print(output_df)
```

which gives

```
                    overlapping_regions        overlapping_labels
0              (chr1:35-55, chr1:45-56)          (label2, label3)
1              (chr1:15-25, chr1:10-20)          (label2, label1)
2  (chr1:45-56, chr1:35-55, chr1:55-60)  (label3, label2, label1)
3              (chr1:45-56, chr1:55-60)          (label3, label1)
```

This should work even with large dataframe. If you still find it slow, you could use `concurrent.futures` from `ProcessPoolExecutor`.